# Payment failed but order is Placed in Laravel with Stripe

Tags: laravel, flutter, stripe-payments, laravel-8, laravel-9

I have integrated stripe payment in flutter app but After payment got failed even then order placed in Laravel database so please check, what I have done wrong.

Please check at save method, May be I am wrong and can't validate purchase response.

payment controller

```
 public function makePayment(Request $request)
    {
        try{
            $data = $request->input('cartItems');
            $cartItems = json_decode($data, true);
            $orderData = $request->input('order');
            $selectPaymentOption = json_decode($orderData, true);
            $totalAmount = 0.0;
            foreach ($cartItems as $cartItem){
                $order = new Order();
                $order->order_date = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
                $order->product_id = $cartItem['productId'];
                $order->payment_type = $selectPaymentOption['paymentType'];
                $order->user_id = $request->input('userId');
                $order->quantity = $cartItem['productQuantity'];
                $order->amount = ($cartItem['productPrice'] - $cartItem['productDiscount']);
                $totalAmount+= $order->amount * $order->quantity;
                $order->save();
            }
            
            if($selectPaymentOption['paymentType'] == 'Card'){
                
            \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_hJUgYYzeXtitxxxx71lK8nE00MELJJS8c');

            $token = \Stripe\Token::create([
                'card' => [
                    'number' => $request->input('cardNumber'),
                    'exp_month' => $request->input('expiryMonth'),
                    'exp_year' => $request->input('expiryYear'),
                    'cvc' => $request->input('cvcNumber')
                ]
            ]);

            $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
                'amount' => $totalAmount * 100,
                'currency' => 'inr',
                'source' => $token,
                'receipt_email' => $request->input('email'),
            ]);
            
        }
            return response(['result' => true]);
            
        } catch (\Exception $exception){
            return response(['result' => $exception]);
        }
    }
```

and my Flutter's Post request is here.
I want to POST _makePayment method after complete payment successful.

```
void _makePayment(BuildContext context, Payment payment) async {
    PaymentService _paymentService = PaymentService();
    var paymentData = await _paymentService.makePayment(payment);
    var result = json.decode(paymentData.body);
    print(paymentData);
    CartService _cartService = CartService();
    this.widget.cartItems!.forEach((cartItem) {
      _cartService.makeTheCartEmpty();
    });
    if (result['result'] == true) {
      _showPaymentSuccessMessage(context);
      Timer(Duration(seconds: 4), () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Well that is because in your code you first create the order in you DB and then you call the stripe SDK, so just switch the stripe logic above declaring the new Order instance and everything should be fine! You can make your life easier by passing total amount from you frontend also (calculate it there and just pass it as a variable).

Comment: @dz0nika Can you help me with switching the logic or suggest me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to my comment above, this is the rough solution I suggested in your controller you have to switch the logic

```
public function makePayment(Request $request)
{
    try{
        $data = $request->input('cartItems');
        $cartItems = json_decode($data, true);
        $orderData = $request->input('order');
        $selectPaymentOption = json_decode($orderData, true);
##Change your frontend logic to pass total amount as variable
        $totalAmount = $request->totalAmount;
        
        if($selectPaymentOption['paymentType'] == 'Card'){
            
##Never have any sk or pk in your controller, switch this to config('common.sk_test')        
          \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(config('common.sk_test'));

           $token = \Stripe\Token::create([
             'card' => [
                'number' => $request->input('cardNumber'),
                'exp_month' => $request->input('expiryMonth'),
                'exp_year' => $request->input('expiryYear'),
                'cvc' => $request->input('cvcNumber')
              ]
           ]);

           $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
              'amount' => $totalAmount * 100,
              'currency' => 'inr',
              'source' => $token,
              'receipt_email' => $request->input('email'),
           ]);
        
          }

##After the stripe transaction is finished you can foreach your cart and do what you need to your database 
        foreach ($cartItems as $cartItem){
                $order = new Order();
                $order->order_date = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
                $order->product_id = $cartItem['productId'];
                $order->payment_type = $selectPaymentOption['paymentType'];
                $order->user_id = $request->input('userId');
                $order->quantity = $cartItem['productQuantity'];
                $order->amount = ($cartItem['productPrice'] - $cartItem['productDiscount']);
                $order->save();
            }
        return response(['result' => true]);
        
    } catch (\Exception $exception){
        return response(['result' => $exception]);
    }
}
```

For the config('common.sk_test') part of my answer, in you config folder you can create a new file where you have you custom app variables, so create a file for instance common.php and 'sk_test' that takes its value from you .env file